# How to push value to nested objects in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, foreach, push

I have the following data:

```
{
    "fruits": [
        {
            "name": "apple",
            "prices": [
                {
                    "2015": 2,
                    "2014": 3,
                    "2013": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "banana",
            "prices": [
                {
                    "2015": 4,
                    "2014": 1,
                    "2013": 3
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In my .js file, inside my controller, I want to calculate the difference between the price of the latest year and the year before.

Such as:

Apples = 3 - 2 = -1

So that in my HTML I can do:

```
<div ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
    {{fruit.name}}, {{fruit.change}}
</div>
```

I've tried the following with no luck:

```
angular.forEach($scope.fruits, function(fruit, key) {
    angular.forEach(fruit.prices, function(price, key) {
        this.change = price[0] - price[1];
    });
});
```

Comment: i think you can doing it inside the view page
bring the two values from controller
and calculate it

Comment: is your data populated by a http call in a factory or is it something else like static json or firebase?

Comment: @JoeLloyd Kind of besides the point…

Comment: @ElieMA No, I need it in the .js file

Comment: @JoeLloyd Yes, correct

Comment: add a new scope that is a function at each level of your data, so something along these lines `$scope.fruits.change = function(){/* your calculation*/}`

Answer (score 1):

Just a typo, instead of `this` use `fruit` and it'll work.

```
function calculate(targetYear){
    angular.forEach($scope.fruits, function(fruit, key) {
        $scope.fruits[key].change = fruit.prices[0][targetYear] - fruit.prices[0][targetYear-1];
    });
}
```

You can use this function like: `calculate(2015)` and it'll set for each `fruit.change` value to show the change between 2015/2014

Comment: reason for downvoting?

Comment: The prices are objects, they don't have keys called `0` or `1`.

Comment: @Juhana How do you get the `0` and `1` of prices?

Comment: @murid They **don't have** such keys. Objects are unordered. If you want to find the key with the highest value, you have to first get the keys, sort them, and then pick the first one.

Comment: Changed. Try it now pls